# Google analytics: dataLayer.push not working with array of variables?

Tags: typescript, google-analytics, arguments, google-analytics-api, gtag.js

I wonder why gtag.js doesn't work when push to dataLayer array of variables instead of 'arguments'? Here is some code example:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []

function gtag(first: any, second: any) {
    window.dataLayer.push([first, second])
}

gtag('js', new Date())
gtag('config', trackingCode)
```

This only works when I replace '[first, second]' with 'arguments'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*We don't know what you're trying to achieve by overwriting the `gtag` function so we can't answer the specific question as to what `"works"` and what doesn't.*

What can be said: [`arguments` is an Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and [GTM expects an object from `dataLayer.push`](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/reference#datalayer.push), hence why this follows the intended design (whereas `[first, second]` is an Array and thus does not).

**Note that the `push` call in itself "works"**:
[image]

**However you won't be able to read that data via GTM** which as explained above expects `.push` to pass Objects.

**If you want to use the dataLayer in a compeltely free way**, you can use the GTM dataLayer helper:
https://github.com/google/data-layer-helper

This does support the array syntax via [Meta commands](https://github.com/google/data-layer-helper#meta-commands):

```
dataLayer.push(['abc.push', 4, 5, 6]);
```

**However GTM by default doesn't support reading this data** (once again GTM expects an Object so it can extract values based on the object properties), so to read that data via GTM you would need to use the dataLayer helper within GTM tags and variables.

Comment: "We don't know what you're trying to achieve by overwriting"


I use typescript and it shows an error when the function doesn't have described argument types :)

Comment: why don't you simply do not declare any specific arguments (which typescript seems to accept in the form of  `function myFunction(...args: any[])` https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20180216-VariableNumberOfArgumentsInTypescript.html) and then pass the `args` Object to `dataLayer.push`?

Comment: Yes, I came to this approach, but I'm just wondering why they need exactly the “IArguments” to be passed to dataLayer. Also I want to mention that simply pass "args" Object to dataLayer.push doesn't work. It works only with 'arguments'

Answer (score 3):

So, at the end, this version of the code works fine for me, without linter errors:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []

function gtag(..._args: unknown[]) {
    window.dataLayer.push(arguments)
}

gtag('js', new Date())
gtag('config', trackingCode)
```